# How to get select2 to match

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to re-create [the most basic "states" select2 example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#single), but it does not match beyond the first letter - just like a normal `select` element. It does seem to be loading select2, for example, it displays the selected value to the right of the `select` element. However, when I try to type a state, it only seems to match the first character. I.e., If I type "t" it will match "Texas", but typing "dak" will match "Delaware" rather than "North Dakota".

I've create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jaymitchell/64f919b59539f9a21ed8cad67e557b44) of my complete html page. I copied the `select` element directly from the example page, so there's not a whole lot to it.

In a nutshell, I create a `select` element with the class `js-example-basic-single`, and then I call `select2()` on that element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
  });
</script>
```

Edit: On [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/yoxavexoyo/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated jsBin](https://jsbin.com/bugega/edit?html,css,output)**.

Check the simple working snippet below based on you gist code, and make sure you're adding the CSS link include :

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({width:'100%'});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```